# Avoid repeating when defining a class in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, ruby-1.9.3

I find my self repeating things a lot when I create classes in ruby, often I will end up with something similar to the following:

```
class Foo
  attr_reader :bar_0,
              :bar_1,
                 .
                 .
                 .
              :bar_n
  def initialize( bar_0 = something,
                  bar_1 = something,
                        .
                        .
                        .
                  bar_n = something)
    @bar_0 = bar_0
    @bar_1 = bar_1
           .
           .
           .
    @bar_n = bar_n
  end
end
```

Does ruby employ a shortcut for more efficiently implementing something like this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Constructor with 50 parameters is ugly in any language.

Comment: it's not that I want to include something which has already been included, I just want to be able to define an instance variable when new is called on the class (`@bar = bar`), set a default value for new (bar = nil), and make it accessible ( `attr_reader`) without having to repeat my self three times

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the way the question is phrased, you should probably rethink the design of your classes. However, Ruby provides an interesting way to quickly create classes with `attr_accessor`s (not readers). Here's a simple example:

```
>> class Person < Struct.new(:name, :age) ; end
=> nil
>> p = Person.new
=> #<struct Person name=nil, age=nil>
>> p.age = 23
=> 23
>> p.class
=> Person
>> p.methods.grep(/age/)
=> [:age, :age=]
```

Of course this is a normal class and you can add all the methods you want (and use getters and setters instead of instance variables, e.g. `var` for the getter and `self.var = foo` for the setter).

If you really don't want the writers, make them private or `undef` them.

```
>> attrs = [:name, :age]
=> [:name, :age]
>> class Person < Struct.new *attrs ; end
=> nil
>> Person.instance_eval { private *attrs.map{|attr| "#{attr}=" }}
=> Person
>> p = Person.new
=> #<struct Person name=nil, age=nil>
>> p.methods.grep(/age/)
=> [:age]
```

All of the above doesn't help with the tons of assignments in `initialize` of course, but then one wonders if you really want to many constructor arguments or if maybe you just have one hash argument and merge that into a default hash.

Comment: I have been wondering weather to just put everything in a hash over so many constructor variable but I would like to have either method of initialization available.  Essentially I am writing a Gem to interface with a REST api and I am working toward it being as conducive as possible to any project it is incorporated into.  SPECIFICALLY I would like each variable extracted from a REST call to be available via `p = Foo.new( argument_0, ..., argument_n)` and/or `p = Foo.new( hash)` and have any argument be available via `p.bar_i`.  A bit of java mindset but useful non the less.

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is dynamic and offers a lot in terms of introspection, so you can make use of metaprogramming (or writing code that essentially writes code). In your example there are several things you can do to clean up the verbosity:

```
class Foo
  # Rather than writing bar_1, bar_2, bar_3, ...
  attr_accessor ((0..9).to_a + ('a'..'n').to_a).map { |x| :"foo_#{x}" }

  # Using mass assignment...
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    attributes.each do |attribute, value|
      respond_to?(:"#{attribute}=") && send(:"#{attribute}=", value)
    end
  end
end
```

Since mass assignment is a popular and reusable behavior, it makes sense to extract it into a separate module and make it a mixin:

```
module MassAssignment
  def initialize(attributes = {})
    mass_assign(attributes)
  end

  def mass_assign(attributes)
    attributes.each do |attribute, value|
      respond_to?(:"#{attribute}=") && send(:"#{attribute}=", value)
    end
  end
end

class Foo
  include MassAssignment
end
```

Comment: `attr_reader ((0..9).to_a + ('a'..'n').to_a).map { |x| :"foo_#{x}" }` I think this is cool example of WTF kind of code. Ruby can do this but I don't think it should be used in live code that would be seen by anybode else.

Comment: Not necessarily a consistant naming convention for bar_i instance variables and I need to be able to set default values.  I would like to be able to the three separate definition I am doing now all in one definition.

Comment: In 1.9 you can create that array like this: `[*0..9, *?a..?n]`. :-)

Comment: I agree that this is pretty gnarly, but I don't think Kurt actually has sequential attributes, just demonstrating that he could dynamically define the attributes if desired. :)

Comment: Yes this code looks crazy but Rails/ActiveRecord does a lot of similar things to make it magical and "just work". Granted, it is a framework, and things like this should probably only be used when you actually need dynamic runtime generation (like you might in a framework/library), rather than for just reducing code within the class itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [introduce parameter object](http://martinfowler.com/refactoring/catalog/introduceParameterObject.html) refactoring method to simplify constructor call.